# Unable to get remote branch on local - Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, github, ssh

I have setup ssh profile on my Ubuntu Machine and it is working fine as well.

Today, my other friend created new branch and pushed the code and branch on heroku.

Now, the problem is that I can't able to pull new branch on my local.

Below are my commands:

```
u@u:~/workspace/abc$ git pull heroku upgrade:master
fatal: Couldn't find remote ref upgradeu@u:~/workspace/abc$ fatal: The 
remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

And if I do git fetch it shows no response.

My git config is:

```
[color]
    ui = true
[user]
    name = user
    email = user@gmail.com
[core]
    autocrlf = input
[push]
    default = simple
[http]
    postBuffer = 157286400
```

my ssh profile:

```
Host heroku.work
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_abc
  Hostname heroku.com
  User user@gmail.com
  IdentitiesOnly yes
```

My remote is:

```
[remote "heroku"]
    url = git@heroku.work:abc.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Comment: The push and pull to heroku master is working perfectly but unable to pull other branches.

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't normally pull another branch. You would switch to it

- Run `git pull heroku` to update your local repository from the remote
- Then use `git branch` to display the available branches
- Lastly use something like `git checkout update` to switch to the branch.